# Community users under which conditions can access (read/write) its contact?

Tags: sharing, customer-community

I'm searching the official documentation that help me to understand how to authorize a customer community user to access and edit its related contact.

searching around i found that it can be done:

- Sharing settings (setting default external access to public read/write)
- Sharing sets

but what i'm not finding...and was wondering I can achive such result also by only giving read and write permissions on users profile.
Does that enable the user to access to its related contact? If so, where this is documented?

Thanks!